# Escape reserved words in an import

Tags: kotlin

When using Java classes in Kotlin, sometimes they use identifiers that are reserved word in kotlin. The java interop documentation says you can use backtick (`) character but this doesn't work in imports. So how to escaped reserved words on import.

e.g. The tinkerpop library has a class called '__' but thats a Kotlin reserved so if I import it like below it gives an error.

```
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.__
```

I can import it using the wild card like this:

```
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.*
```

but because I only use the one class then Intellij's code formatter replaces it with the previous version of the import that gives an error. (Which I guess is a bug in the intellij formatter as well)

For the answers that suggest using backtick ` works. It does not. This does not compile even on try.kotlinlang.org.
Assuming a class exists defined as

```
package blah

class `__` {

}
```

This is what happens when you import it with backticks.
[image: Escapingdoesnotcompile]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method I've found that works is to import it with an alias which is ok but it does change the name used in code.

```
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.__ as underscore
```

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: I am not a Kotlin user.

The Kotlin Grammar page ( https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#SimpleName ) states that the `import` keyword is followed by a `SimpleName ("." SimpleName)` where `SimpleName` is defined as either `<java identifier>` or ``` "``" <java identifier> "``" ```

According to the above rules, each component that needs escaping should be surrounded in single backtick characters. As only the last name is reserved your code should look like this:

```
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.`__`
```

I tried using this in an online Kotlin tool ( http://try.kotlinlang.org/ ) and the syntax was accepted.

### Update

I created a 2-file program in try.kotlinlang.org and I can reproduce the problem, and fix it.

So the issue isn't just that keywords and other reserved words need to be escaped with backticks (though in this case, the name `__` (two underscores) is not a keyword in Kotlin, but that Kotlin does not seem to allow reserved names to even exist in-scope!

Here's my test-case:

#### File1.kt

```
package blah

class `__` {
    fun foo(): Int {
        return 5
    }
}
```

#### File2.kt

```
import blah.__

fun test2() {
    val us = __()
    us.foo
}
```

This gives me this compile-time error:

> `File2.kt` - Error:(1,) Names _, **, _**, ..., are reserved in Kotlin

If I change `File2.kt` to this, then it works fine:

```
import blah.__ as underscore

fun test2() {
    val us = underscore()
    us.foo
}
```

Using backticks doesn't seem to help at all, but it does give me unexpected errors:

```
import blah.`__` as `__`

fun test2() {
    val us = `__`()          <-- error is here
    us.foo()
}
```

> `File2.kt` - Error: (4, 13) Unresolved reference: `__`

Variations of the names with backticks and unescaped double-underscores yields no effect.

So it seems the solution is to alias the name to something else during import.

Comment: This doesn't compile. See screenshot from updated answer.

Comment: @LionelPort I typed the exact same code into try.kotlinlang.org at my end and it worked - are you typing a different backtick character? What keyboard layout are you using? Is your computer set to a different locale or encoding?

Comment: Its the backtick character (left of the 1 on an us intl keyboard layout). It works fine in code blocks just not in imports. I had defined the "__" class separately in the blah package so maybe that's why you don't see the error. I've updated my answer to show a definition of the class.

Comment: @LionelPort I can now reproduce the problem and I have found a solution. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Yes that was the conclusion I had yesterday (see answer below). You can wild card (*) import or alias. Really seems like a bug to me that it's not consistently applied.

Comment: Fun fact: There is a method "as()" in gremlin in the __ class. So one would need the import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.__.as to use in the query DSL. I tried several things but could nt get that one to work

Answer (score 0):

As specified in the docs, your import must look like:

```
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.`__`
```

Then to use the underscore symbol in the code you'll have to escape it every time, so an alias is the best solution:

```
`__`.foo()
```

Docs: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#escaping-for-java-identifiers-that-are-keywords-in-kotlin

Comment: This does not compile. See screenshot from updated answer.

Comment: that might be a bug in the parser